# jQuery callback function accumulating

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, jquery-callback

I wrote some code for a custom confirm box that calls a function when confirm button (yes-button) is pressed and passes another function as a parameter and I bind it to 2 different button clicks with different functions as a parameter. For example:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    callFunction(function() { alert("test"); });
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
    callFunction(function() { alert("test2"); });
});

function callFunction(callback) {
    //code to display custom confirm box

    console.log(callback);

    $('.confirm-box .yes-button').click(function() {
        callback();
    });
}
```

Everything happens as expected, confirm box appears and on confirm button click I get a callback function executed and it alerts "test" (or "test2" depending on which button called the confirm box). The problem arises when I click button1 that sends a function that alerts "test", then instead of confirming I cancel that (nothing happens as expected), and then click button2 that passes alert("test2") as a callback function. Now once I press the yes-button instead of alerting just "test2", I get both "test2" and "test" alerts even though that console.log I wrote logs just the function that alerts "test2" at the time of that button2 click. It seems like these callback functions get stacked somewhere, but I don't understand where and why.

Comment: Try overwriting `callback` in a global scope instead of declaring each time another `click` event

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind an event handler inside another event handler, it usually results in unwanted accumulation like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .click() function can add more than one handler to an element, and I think that's what's happening here. Try this:

```
// ...
$('.confirm-box .yes-button').unbind('click').click(function() {
    callback();
});
```

This removes any previous click handler before applying the new one.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and I'll probably accept it as correct. Just gonna wait if Stryner has a comment because I would accept his answer instead if it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the code:

```
$('.confirm-box .yes-button').click(function() {
    callback();
});
```

you are binding an event handler to the `.yes-button` element. If you run that code twice, it will have two events bound to it. And so on.

One solution is to use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead, so that the event handler will be removed after the first time it is fired:

```
$('.confirm-box .yes-button').one("click", function() {
    callback();
});
```

This of course has issues if there are two confirm boxes open simultaneously or if there are two `.yes-button` elements, but for a simple use case it works fine.

Comment: I really hoped this would be the answer as it seems the most "intuitive" way to write it, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It still stacks up those callback functions. I think it's because .one unbinds the event from button only after it's been executed, so if I cancel confirmation 2-3 times that code will never get executed and won't have the chance to unbind event, and will instead just stack those callback functions.

Comment: @MarioPlantosar I hadn't considered that. If they press cancel, this method definitely won't work. Unbinding the event is the way to go. I'd also suggest using an [event namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) so that you don't accidentally unbind any other click events on the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting an identity by classes,

```
var button = $('.confirm-box .yes-button');

$('#button1').click(function() {
  button.removeClass("b").addClass("a");
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
  button.removeClass("a").addClass("b");
});

button.click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("a")){
     callBackForButton1();
  } else {
     callBackForButton2();
  }
});
```

It is a bad practice to stack up the event handler for a single element.

Comment: We can stress the first-order nature of JavaScript functions by writing `function() { ($(this).hasClass("a") ? callBackForButton1 : callBackForButton2)(); }` instead of an if-else.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I would like to avoid something like this. I need it for a custom confirm box, so with your code I would have to write a switch statement with cases for each confirmation I have on my website.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that each time a button is clicked the callFunction method is executing. It runs through that code block and applies an event listener to the  $('.confirm-box .yes-button') button. So clicking your button N times will apply the click listener N times as well. One solution is to store the function in a variable.

Not sure what the end goal is, but this is one solution. 
Another solution would be to remove buttons event listeners each time.

```
var functionToCallOnYes = function() {};

$('#button1').click(function() {
  functionToCallOnYes = function() {
    alert("test");
  };

});

$('#button2').click(function() {
  functionToCallOnYes = function() {
    alert("test2");
  };
});


$('.confirm-box .yes-button').click(function() {
  console.log(functionToCallOnYes);
  functionToCallOnYes();
});
```

Comment: This was the solution I was going to suggest, although all the methods are reasonable.

Comment: @Barmar I agree! Learned a new one myself.  I do hope OP understands that binding the same event multiple times to only execute it once may not be the best solution most of the time.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct, but in my use case it's not really the way to go. I need it for a custom confirm box, so I would like to have the ability to pass callback function as a parameter. That way I can write something like confirm("Are you sure you want to do that?", function () { //do something if confirmed });

Comment: Very possible that your situation requires a different approach! Still think something like this could work though. :)
`function confirm(questionStr, yesFunction){                                                   
//Open/show confirm box with questionStr                                                      
$('#yesbutton').on('click', yesFunction);                                                          
$('#nobutton').on('click', function(){ //close confirm box })                          
}`

Comment: But the function you wrote is no different than mine, except that you don't pass the actual callback function as a parameter but a reference to it. That #yesbutton click will still stack yes functions, and if I have 2 confirm boxes with different callback functions, both of them will get executed if I choose one confirm box, cancel it and then choose the other and confirm. That canceled callback should not get executed but it will in this case because it was attached to #yesbutton even though I canceled that first confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, extra callbacks are getting stacked up. In `$('button1').click(f)`, the function `f` will be called with no parameters every time `button1` is clicked. In this case, `f` is `callFunction`-- a function that itself attaches a new handler to any `.confirm-box .yes-button` element each time it's invoked. So on the Nth click, you should have N-1 alerts.

To make things like this easier, you can refer to functions by name in JavaScript. So if you had `function test() { console.log("test"); };`, you could write `$(".confirm-box").click(test)` just once and every click on a `.confirm-box` from then on would print `test` to the console.

Usually if you have callbacks whose sole purpose is to call a callback, you can just remove that callback.